# Do some browsers require the Origin header to be explicitly allowed for CORS to succeed?

Tags: cors, http-headers, fetch, user-agent

Among popular CORS middleware libraries for Go is [rs/cors](https://github.com/rs/cors). In its source code, above some logic that unconditionally adds `Origin` to the list of allowed headers, I found [the following comment](https://github.com/rs/cors/blob/master/cors.go#L165):

> Origin is always appended as some browsers will always request for this header at preflight

I find this statement surprising... [The Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) (the de factor standard for the CORS protocol) states that compliant user agents set the `Origin` header themselves. Therefore, there should be no use for compliant user agents to require servers to explicitly list `Origin` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header.

Do some wacky browsers actually require the `Origin` header to be explicitly allowed by the server for CORS to succeed? If so, what are those browsers and what is their rationale?

Comment: What is 'allowed' and not only applies to user-land code. The Origin header is not set by the user, it's set by the browser itself and it does not need to be allowed explicitly.

Comment: @Evert Thanks, but you're not really answering my question :)

Comment: "it does not need to be allowed explicitly." - didn't?

Comment: @Evert I interpret your comment as: "the Fetch standard doesn't require `Origin` to be allowed explicitly". I know that ; what I am asking is whether some (non-compliant) browsers out there actually do require it.

Comment: Popular updated ones: no. Could there be an obscure/outdated version out there that requires it? Hard to say. I've worked on massive applications and this has never been an issue for me.

Comment: @Evert _Could there be an obscure/outdated version out there that requires it?_ That's what I want to know :)

Comment: The issue with these questions is that you can never get a definite 'no', because someone out there might have a weird copy of a browser on their disk that we'll never find out about :P. But you might get a `yes`. Since this is asking in the context of a go package, perhaps the addition of the `Origin` header is motivated in the commit that added it.

Comment: @Evert Good call! Let me reach for `git blame`.

Comment: I found: https://github.com/rs/cors/commit/6e0c3cb65fc0fdb064c743d176a620e3ca446dfb

My guess is that they probably didn't realize it's not needed. `Origin` can't even be overridden by the user, so it makes no sense. You could also always ask them.